# Why can DateComponentsFormatter produce different results if I pass a TimeInterval VS let it calculate the TimeInterval itself?

Tags: ios, swift

I've noticed what appears to be an inconsistency when using the DateComponentsFormatter class. Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly or maybe this is actually what's supposed to happen.

In the below code I create 2 dates and then create an interval string. However if I use method 1 which is currently commented I get a different result than method 2.

```
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2000/01/01 00:00:00") ?? Date()
    let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2001/02/02 01:01:01") ?? Date()

    let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
    dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

    // Method 1 - produces "1y 1mo 1d 1h 1min. 1s."
    // let outputString = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: date1, to: date2)

    // Method 2 - produces "1y 1mo 2d 1h 1min. 1s."
    let timeInterval: TimeInterval = date2.timeIntervalSince(date1)
    let outputString = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: timeInterval)
```

Even more interestingly, if I reverse the dates in both methods, method 1 remains consistent just adding a negative sign, where as method 2 adds a negative sign but also changes from 2 days to 1 day which is the same result as method 1.

So the question is, why does method 2 not work consistently? Using the following random dates I get either 1 or 0 days depending on which method I use.

```
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020/11/24 17:02:39") ?? Date()
    let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2021/12/25 18:03:40") ?? Date()
```

Is there an explanation for this or am I doing something wrong? What am I missing? It seems like it's method 2 that's the problem. Could it be that the timeIntervalSince function is at fault? But shouldn't it have the same implementation as the dateComponentsFormatter function?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because a time interval has no reference to any calendar, locale and or timezones (No daylight savings transitions). You should stick with method one and make sure to use the correct calendar, locale and timezone when parsing your date strings

Comment: Yeah I think I'll stick with method 1. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw time interval has no leap years either. And don't forget to set your date components formatter calendar and the calendar locale and timezone as well